# "Invalid Property Value"

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I make the button Next data in my data, and the data there's get 
 DatePicker value. 
This Code :

```
Private Sub lanjut_Click()
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Sheet5.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If currentrow = lastrow Then
    MsgBox "Anda sudah berada dibaris terakhir!.", vbInformation, "Message"
    Exit Sub
End If

currentrow = currentrow + 1

nis = Cells(currentrow, 1)
namasiswa = Cells(currentrow, 2) 
jk = Cells(currentrow, 3)
nisn = Cells(currentrow, 4)
tempat_lahir = Cells(currentrow, 5)
tanggal_lahir = Cells(currentrow, 6).Value
nik = Cells(currentrow, 7)
agama = Cells(currentrow, 8)
alamat = Cells(currentrow, 9)
rt = Cells(currentrow, 10)
rw = Cells(currentrow, 11)
dusun = Cells(currentrow, 12)
kelurahan = Cells(currentrow, 13)
kecamatan = Cells(currentrow, 14)
kabupatenkota = Cells(currentrow, 15)
provinsi = Cells(currentrow, 16)
kodepos = Cells(currentrow, 17)
jenis_tinggal = Cells(currentrow, 18)
transportasi = Cells(currentrow, 19)

End Sub
```

I use DatePicker in Code **tanggal_lahir = Cells(currentrow, 6).Value** and i run it, it's error message

> "Invalid Property Value"

How to solve it? Thanks

Comment: When it errors, go to your debug window and type `? Cells(currentrow, 6).Value` to print the value. What do you get?

Comment: Where and how is `tanggal_lahir` declared?